# How to unchecked the checked checkbox?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, checkbox, android-widget

how to clear the checked box after we get the checked result ?

something like `selection.clear();` but, that only clear the output, not the checkbox.

what i am trying to do is, to set the checkbox to the original state, which is unchecked.

after user checked the checkbox then click button to get result of checked checkbox, i wish to clear all the selection in the checkbox. how please help?

```
public class DessertIngAvail extends Dessert {

ArrayList<String> selection = new ArrayList<String>();
TextView final_text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dessert_ing_avail);

    final_text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.final_result);
    final_text.setEnabled(false);
}

public void selectItem(View view){
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
    switch (view.getId()) {
         case R.id.checkBox181:
            if(checked) {
                if(!selection.contains("Tebaloi"))
                    selection.add("Tebaloi");

                if(!selection.contains("Tumpik"))
                    selection.add("Tumpik");
            }

            break;

        case R.id.checkBox182:
            if(checked) {
                if(!selection.contains("Ambuyat"))
                    selection.add("Ambuyat");
            }

            break;

        case R.id.checkBox183:
            if(checked) {
                if(!selection.contains("Tumpik"))
                    selection.add("Tumpik");
            }

            break;

        case R.id.checkBoxCM:
            if(checked) {

                if(!selection.contains("Honey Frankincense Cake"))
                    selection.add("Honey Frankincense Cake");

                if(!selection.contains(" Ray Heart Cake"))
                    selection.add(" Ray Heart Cake");
            }

            break;
    }
}

public void finalSelection(View view) {

    String final_fruit_selection = "";

    for(String Selection : selection) {
        final_fruit_selection = final_fruit_selection + Selection + "\n";
    }

    final_text.setText(final_fruit_selection);
    selection.clear();

    final_text.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
checkBox.setChecked(boolean);
//to clear the check box
checkBox.setChecked(false);
```

Updated finalSelection(View view) method;

```
public void finalSelection(View view){
    String final_fruit_selection = "";
    for(String Selection : selection){
       final_fruit_selection = final_fruit_selection + Selection + "\n";
    }
    final_text.setText(final_fruit_selection);
    selection.clear();
    final_text.setEnabled(true);

    //now clear checkboxes
    checkBox181.setChecked(false);
    checkBox182.setChecked(false);
    checkBox183.setChecked(false);
    checkBoxCM.setChecked(false);
}
```

Changing really really really basic things

```
//right below TextView final_text; at the top add this
CheckBox checkBox181,checkBox182,checkBox183,checkBoxCM;

//declare then in onCreate()
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_dessert_ing_avail);

   final_text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.final_result);
   final_text.setEnabled(false);
   checkBox181=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox181);
   checkBox182=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox182);
   checkBox183=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox183);
   checkBoxCM=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxCM);
}
```

I suggest you to follow up some java course online. [This](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/) is a good place to start.

To start learning android development check [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html).

Comment: where should i implement that line? in `public void final selection` ?

Comment: Yep. You can do it anywhere you want. But yeah totally you can do it on final_selection method.

Comment: do i have to declare anything? because it cannot resolve the symbol checkBox

Comment: its any of the checkboxes you have in your code like ckeckBox183

Comment: sorry i don't understand..i am new to this

Comment: oowwhh i see..now i understand. fuuh..there are no simpler way to do so?

Comment: sorry..it still show up the checkbox id in red colour. cannot resolve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112775/discussion-between-silver-damsel-and-malith-lakshan).

Answer (score 1):

To check:

```
checkBox.setChecked(true);
```

and to uncheck:

```
checkBox.setChecked(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setChecked()`:

```
checkBox.setChecked(true/false)
```

Docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question but you can set a checkbox by using `checkBox.setChecked(false)`. To uncheck all checked checkboxes, simply loop over them and uncheck the checked ones.

Comment: how to loop over them? sorry i am new in this thing

Comment: If those checkboxes are the only ones, looping is not necessary. Just do `checkBox.setChecked(false)` four times. Instead of `checkBox` use `(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.my_checkbox)`.

Comment: actually those are not full code..i have more than four checkbox. many checkbox. so how? do i have to declare each one of them by Id?

Comment: Are you using a listadapter to do so?

Comment: Then I'm afraid you have to findViewById all of them. Consider using an adapter in the future.

Comment: i get you..can u show me how to use adapter in my case?

Comment: You can check out an example here: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-listview-with-adapter-example.html

Answer (score 0):

If you'r sure checkbox are checked, You can toggle them.

```
checkbox.toggle();
```

Otherwise

```
checkBox.setChecked(false); // pass true if you want to select.
```